# Visual Studio C# Project Template #if DEBUG #endif disappear in produced projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio, compiler-directives

I have Visual Studio C# project template with `#if DEBUG` `#endif` directives like this:

```
#if DEBUG
...
#endif
```

But when I creating project from this template it doesn't contain this part. Can I somehow make it to be in projects that created from this template?

Comment: Maybe the sharp sign (i.e **#**) is a special symbol used when designing templates (like the dollar sign **$** too). Try to put the whole directives in block comments, and test the creation again. If the commented lines appear in a new project, then my theory is correct and there must be a way to escape the symbol **#**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-project-templates?view=vs-2022) to create a template.

My test environment: vs 2022 17.4.1 C# .Net 6.0

The template created by `Export Template` can correctly create what you want when added.

[image]

Demo:

[image]

Comment: You created project 72 but still show Program.cs from 71

Comment: @Kazbek sorry,I made a mistake. I have edited it. Please check it.